# Returning value to function inside another nested function

Tags: javascript, function, nested, return

So I have this javascript code. There are 2 nested functions. How can I return a value to `funcA()` inside `funcB()` ?

```
function funcA() {
   funcB(() => {
        //return funcA inside here 
    })
}
```

Is this even possible without doing it like the following?

```
function funcA() {
    let returnValueA;
    funcB(() => {
        //change returnValueA inside here
    })
    return returnValueA;
}
```

Comment: in your example, `returnValueB` is not defined, and `funcB` is never called and `returnValueA` is never used ... so .. the answer is a pineapple

Comment: I think the keyword is "recursion"

Comment: @agentp — No. That would be if `funcA` conditionally called *itself*.

Comment: It depends on what `funcB` does. If it's a *synchronous* callback, there may be things you can do and/or `funcB` should handle the return value appropriately. If it's an *asynchronous* callback, there's no way.

Comment: @Quentin Indeed, the question has been thoroughly edeted multiple times. But it's still [possible](https://jsfiddle.net/br6jxgu0/1/), `return funcB(...)`, if `funcB` is synchronous, and returns a value created by the callback.

Comment: For some reason I can't answer. Check out generators: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: Thanks for the help to y'all! I have made a few typing mistakes when publishing the question. Sorry if the edits were confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

A `return` statement only defines what is returned from the function it is part of.